# How to continuously check if a key is pressed before continuing?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to continuously check whether or not a key is pressed. Once it is, I want run a block of code. Here's how I'm trying to implement it as of now:

```
func someFunctionCall {
  //do stuff here
  //check until key is pressed
  while(!spacePressed) {
    if(spacePressed) {
      //do more stuff in here
    }
  }
}
```

And here's where I detect key presses:

```
public override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) { 
     switch Int(event.keyCode) {
     case kVK_Space:
    spacePressed = true
     default:
    break
     }
}

public override func keyUp(with event: NSEvent) {   
     switch Int(event.keyCode) {
     case kVK_Space:
    spacePressed = false
     default:
    break
     }
}
```

I want the while loop to continuously check for the key press until it happens. When I run my program, it freezes when that while loop starts (I'm assuming it's stuck in an infinite loop). Is this even the right way to go about solving the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your "Main thread" is executing your loop continually, so can't execute other instructions.

So you could call your function when your space is key down.

Something like this:

```
var timer:Timer?   

func someFunctionCall() {
   // do exterior loop stuff here
} 




func didSpaceDown(){
timer =  Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true) { (timer) in
       //Do your inside loop stuff here
    }
}

 override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) { 
     if Int(event.keyCode) == KVK_Space{
             didSpaceDown()
         }
 }

 override func keyUp(with event: NSEvent) {   
          if Int(event.keyCode) == KVK_Space{
            timer.invalidate()
         }
 }
```

Try it and tell me. I'm not sure if this works for you.